# R GGally Package ggpairs function correlation asterisks

Tags: r, ggpairs

I am using the ggpairs functionality and having the correlation info appear in the upper boxes.

What I am unable to find anywhere is that some of the values displayed have three asterisks next to them while some do not[image]

Can someone school me as to what these are since I am drawing a blank

Comment: Can you share the data you used to generate these plots and the code you use to make these plots?

Comment: add this to your question not a comment

Comment: Checkout the [ggally_cor](https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/reference/ggally_cor.html) help page. It explains what the asterisks/"stars" are for.

Comment: Thought I had checked this location so appreciate the information.